# How can I create a polygon body in Box2D Android?

Tags: android, box2d

I am new to androidBox2D and I want to create a polygon body such as a rectangle or a triangle 
using Box2D in Android.

I was not getting the `B2FixtureDef` in my code when I was creating a body. What may be the reason for that?

But I am getting `BBFixtureDef`. What is the difference between `B2FixtureDef` and `BBFixtureDef`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for my `Box2D (LibGDX box2D library)`:

```
CODE:
            protected static CCSprite _rect1 = null;
....
            _rect1 = CCSprite.sprite("NAMEOFIMAGE.png");
            _rect1.setPosition(CGPoint.make(-10, -10));
            this.addChild(_rect1);
            //Create box
            BodyDef Box1BodyDef = new BodyDef();
            Box1BodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
            Box1BodyDef.position.set(350/PTM_RATIO, 80/PTM_RATIO);

            // The body is also added to the world.
            Body Box1Body = _world.createBody(Box1BodyDef);
            Box1Body.setUserData(_rect1);

            // Define the shape.
            PolygonShape Box1Box = new PolygonShape();


            Box1Box.setAsBox(10/PTM_RATIO, 50/PTM_RATIO);
            Box1Body.createFixture(Box1Box,1.5f);
```